# TSP polynomial Time

Tags: algorithms, graphs

How can it be proved that TSP cannot be solved in polynomial time ( Please bear that I don't have a hardcore computer science background).

Comment: Nobody knows. This is the P vs. NP question. If you manage that TSP cannot be solved in polynomial time, you are eligible for a one million dollar Clay prize.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answering it would require major research advances.

Comment: Proving that TSP cannot be solved in polynomial time would lead to a break-through in mathematics.  The 1 million dollars prize would be the least of your worries.  If you prove that TSP cannot be solved in polynomial time, you have proven that [P is not equal to NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem).

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Instead of closing, perhaps just move the comments into an answer?

Comment: I have summarized what has been said by Yuval and Pal, and added a little about reductions between problems. Feel free to edit or add a new answer if you feel mine is inadequate.

Answer (score 3):

It's an open problem whether or not the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP) can be solved in polynomial time. Proving that this is not possible would imply that $P 
\neq NP$.

What is known though, is that TSP is just as hard as a variety of other problems, such as SAT or the CLIQUE problem. In particular, if we could solve SAT efficiently (which most people believe isn't possible - though no proof exists), then we could also solve TSP efficiently. This can be shown by a process called a Polynomial Time Reduction between both problems. In other words, the goal is to transform an instance of TSP into an instance of SAT, then using the solution to that SAT instance to obtain a solution to your original TSP instance. If you are interested, then I recommend you look into the complexity classes $NP$ and $NPC$, and read about polynomial-time reductions between problems in this class.